# How to plot date data evenly along x-axis?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting data from a csv file with the values on the y-axis and the date on the x-axis. My dataset only includes data from June, July and August over a 15 year period. However, when I try to plot this data, it plots all of the dates on the x-axis throughout the period rather than just the summer months in the csv file. Below is what my plot currently looks like

[image]

Here is the code that produced this image:

```
infile = r'data.csv'

with open(infile,'r') as f:
    data = list(reader(f))

date = [parser.parse(i[10]) for i in data[1:]] #3
date = mdates.date2num(date)
date = mdates.num2date(date)

value = [i[16] for i in data[1:]]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(date, value, '.r')
```

Essentially, I am trying to get this same plot without all of the spaces between the each year's data.

Here is what snipet of my data looks like (with years from 2002-2016). The date column (column L) consists of strings. This data is from a csv file just displayed in Excel.
[image]

Comment: You could set `xticks` but I think your plot would become nonsensical? You'd have a mass off points all over the graph and uneven jumps everywhere along the x-axis.  Visually, that would be meaningless to me compared to your current graph.

Comment: Of* sorry, and your question states "evenly along x-axis" which is exactly what you already have. Your desire seems to be to have an _uneven_ x-axis and unless you plan to do something more with that plot, it really would be one of the most confusing graphs I've ever seen. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: I can see where your confusion lies. All of my data is from the same three months each year so ideally I would like the x-axis to read more like: 


06/2013, 07/2013, 08/2013, 06/2014, 07/2014, 08/2014,...etc.

It is hard to see anything in the plot as is, and it think making the x-axis consist of only those three months would make it more useful visually.

Comment: ... I also prefer your current representation. But you could just make an array or list with numpy.arange or range and use that for the x-axis parameter then change the x-axis tick labels to the corresponding dates.  If you look through [the gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) or  [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) you should find code that [does those things](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick_labels_from_values.html).

Comment: I think you're probably trying to show too much information in a single plot. Are you mainly trying to show a trend over years, or over months within a year? If it's the former then I would stick with something similar to what you already have. If it's the latter then you could do something like having months along the x-axis and plotting separate lines to represent each year. You might also want to aggregate your data by computing averages/confidence intervals within each year or month depending on the point you're trying to make.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? If not, what is the structure of the data? An index with dates formatted like 2014-07-01? And multiple categories (columns)?

Comment: @vestland I added a screenshot of what my data looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could imagine using as many subplots as there are date ranges could be an option. For simplicity, you may plot all data to all subplots, but limit each of the subplots to one date range.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(24191)
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

## generate some data x and y
n= 1000
year = np.random.randint(2000,2009, size=n)
month = np.random.randint(6,9, size=n)
day = np.random.randint(1,32, size=n)
x = [datetime.date(y,m,d) for y,m,d in zip(year,month,day)]
y = np.abs(np.random.randn(n))

## define the ranges for the dates
drange = [[datetime.date(i,6,1),datetime.date(i,8,31)] for i in range(2000,2009)]

## create as many subplots as there are date ranges
fig, axes= plt.subplots(ncols=len(drange), sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3,wspace=0)

ymax = 1.1*y.max()
## loop over subplots and limit each to one date range
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.set_xlim(drange[i][0],drange[i][1])
    ax.set_ylim(0,ymax)
    ax.scatter(x,y, s=4)
    loc = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator([6,7,8])
    fmt =  matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%b")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
    if i!=0:
        ax.tick_params(axis="y", which="both", length=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So is this answer then what you want? If not, you would probably want to tell in how far it does not help or what else you would like to achieve. Simply looking at the newly added data in the question, this seems pretty straight-forward to implement in the code above.

Comment: The addition of the vertical lines is integral for this plot. I never envisioned it making sense but I guess it can with that simple modification.

Comment: @roganjosh What do you mean? Would you like to have the plot without vertical lines? (They come for free here, and are quite handy, because they split the plot such the reader is not confused by the broken data axis.)

Comment: In my comments under the main question, I envisioned a plot without those vertical lines. Without them, the uneven jumps in the x axis made me think how it would be a nonsensical mess. The vertical lines make this; I gave you an up vote for demonstrating this could work and proving me wrong (I neglected to envision distinct boundaries) :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I totally agree that some kind of boundary is desirable. Instead of lines one may also use two different shades of the same color in the background or differently colored scatter points; I think there are many options.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you simply want to plot the data against a uniform array and then set the ticks to the dates,

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dates = ['06/2015','07/2015','08/2015', '06/2016','07/2016','08/2016']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%m/%Y').date() for d in dates]
y = range(len(x)) + np.random.random(len(x))

#Plot vs dates
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].plot(x,y,'r.')

#Plot vs number and label
ax[1].plot(y,'r.')
ax[1].set_xticks(range(len(y)))
ax[1].set_xticklabels(dates)
plt.show()
```

Which looks like this,

[image]

Comment: Since OP did not specify the data (yet), this is for sure a valid answer. It's an easy solution for the special case where you have exactly one data point per month. I'm currently not sure how to extend it to the general case, where you might have arbitrary data points (like in the data from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45716573/4124317)).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a screen shot of what my data looks like in OP.

Comment: Ah I see @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I guess you could add a skip on the tick labels, `set_xticklabels(dates[::10])` to prevent overcrowding but I agree it's not the best solution for the general case. I've upvoted your answer :)